# Preconditions check in ruby

Tags: ruby

Very new to ruby and couldn't find much online hence this question. Are there any checks like in java `checkNotNull()` in ruby? Currently, am just doing

```
if var_a.nil? || var_b.nil? || var_c.nil?
  raise "var_a, var_b and var_c cannot be nil"
end
```

Which I feel is a very bad way of checking pre-conditions

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var_a.nil?`?

Comment: @WaleedKhan you are right, didn't get much sleep last night :)

Comment: What's Java `checkNotNull`, and why is it different from what you're doing here?

Comment: @WaleedKhan http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html There is nothing different, just wondered if there are any classes that would allow me to do that without having to write if conditions myself

Comment: http://rubygems.org/gems/preconditions

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like:

```
raise "var_a should not be nil" if var_a.nil?
```

But really not much can be improved in code simplicity here. Still most of the code above is the error message itself so it seems fine to me.

Comment: Actually this way seems better as it focuses on the variable, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it to this:

```
raise "var_a, var_b and var_c cannot be nil" if [var_a, var_b, var_c].any?(&:nil?)
```